# Google BigQuery method InsertRowsAsync() not inserting data into the table

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I have an application that saves query history from different customers, which is run as a cron job. The list queryEntries typically has about 10-3000 records. This is a snippet of the problem area:

```cs
private void Run()
{ 
   foreach(customer in customers)
   {
      List<QueryEntry> queryEntries = bigQueryDataAccess.GetNewQueries(customer);

      if (queryEntries.Any())
      {                    
          bigQueryDataAccess.SaveQueriesToMasterTableAsync(queryEntries);
      }
   }
}
public class BigQueryDataAccess{ 
    public async Task SaveQueriesToMasterTableAsync(List<QueryEntry> queryEntries) 
    {
        BigQueryInsertRow[] rows = new 
        BigQueryInsertRow[queryEntries.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < queryEntries.Count; i++)
        {         
            // Using streaming insert
            BigQueryInsertRow row = new BigQueryInsertRow(insertId: "row" + i){
            {"customer_id", queryEntries[i].CustomerId },
            {"query", queryEntries[i].Query },
            {"start_time", queryEntries[i].StartTime},
            {"end_time", queryEntries[i].EndTime}                 
            };
        rows[i] = row;        
        }     
    _bigQueryClientMaster.InsertRowsAsync("dataset_id", "table_id", rows);
    }
}
```

The InsertRowsAsync method only works sometimes on a small number of rows. Upon debugging the task returns the following:
`Id = 23264, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"`

Things I tried:

```cs
await _bigQueryClientMaster.InsertRowsAsync("dataset_id", "table_id", rows);
```

Also removed the insertId.

Still doesn't work. I'm not sure what else I need to do. New to async programming. Please help

There are no null rows or exceptions. What could be the issue? How do I fix this? Is there any alternative?

Comment: Currently it doesn't look like you're awaiting the task. You should wait for it to complete. (Beyond that, it's hard to say anything really... a [mcve] would help. Note that "similar to the code I have" isn't nearly as useful as "this is code that demonstrates the problem" - often simplifying real code but not reproducing the issue ends up with code that is fine, because the problem has been removed...)

Comment: @Jonskeet thanks for these suggestions. I have edited my question to include more details. Hope this is sufficient to reproduce the issue

Comment: Well it's definitely not a [mcve]. In particular, we don't know what happens after `Run()` completes - which it will do extremely quickly, because you're not waiting for any of the asynchronous operations to finish. If your process ends when `Run()` finishes, that may well be the problem. If you don't want to the asynchronous operations properly (awaiting them at some point), just use the synchronous operations instead.

Comment: Also note that putting an await inside `SaveQueriesToMasterTableAsync` but then not awaiting the return value of that method means you're *still* not really waiting for the operation to complete.